# Which permissions are required to create an issue via Github API v3

Tags: go, github-api

When I try to create an issue with `go-github` API using a personal access token 
it responds with a `401 bad credentials` error:

```
POST https://api.github.com/repos/mh-cbon/demotest/issues: 401 Bad credentials []
```

I am using the following code:

```
input := &github.IssueRequest{
    Title:    &g.IssueTitle,
    Body:     &body,
}

ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(
    &oauth2.Token{AccessToken: g.Token},
)
tc := oauth2.NewClient(oauth2.NoContext, ts)
client := github.NewClient(tc)

  _, _, err = client.Issues.Create(g.Owner, g.Repo, input)
```

The `g.Token` is the value of the token I created with the following permissions:

```
repo
repo:status
repo:repo_deployment 
repo:public_repo
user
user:email
user:follow
```

Comment: `repo` should be enough to create an issue. I would expect if the scopes were incorrect that you would receive a 404 error as GitHub would hide the repo from view, so I wonder if there's some other problem with your token?

Comment: I tried two things, give all permissions to the token, it did not work. Then, i tried with a basic auth (user+pwd auth), it worked. No clue.

Comment: That's really strange. As it happens, I just went to look at the issues list in `go-github`'s repo and found someone with exactly the same problem you describe ;)

Comment: yes! btw, shame on me, I let a damn space hanging in my token.... This explained that. To answer the initial question, `public_repo` is required to create issues!

Comment: Thanks for explaining—glad you got it sorted!